# Selenium Webdriver cannot locate element using Xpath/Css into ubuntu server, but working fine in window browser

Tags: angularjs, ubuntu, selenium, webdriver

Our application front end page is a mixture of html+Angular.js scripts and our Selenium Webdriver script is successfully able to locate the element using xpath/css into window ff browser while execution, but same script is getting failed into ubuntu server headless ff browser with showing below error log.

**Error Log**: `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='main-content']/div[@ng-controller='AdminHome']"}`

**HTML of webpage:**

```
<html class="ng-scope" lang="en" ng-app="anMain">
<head>
<body>
    <div id="app" class="ng-scope" ng-controller="AppCntl">
            <div class="nav-container" style="z-index: 4000; position: relative;">
            <div class="container asAssembly" ng-class="{topMinus: greyBread === true, topMinusSelect: greyBread === true && greyBreadSelect == true, fixedWidth: fixedWidth === true}">
                <div class="gradient_back ng-hide" ng-show="greyBread"></div>
                <div id="main-content" class="ng-scope" ng-hide="AILoading" ng-view="">
                    <div class="container-fluid my_width posts-list-container ng-scope" ng-controller="AdminHome">
                    <h2>Admin home</h2>
                    <br/>
                    <!-- ngIf: areTabsVisible -->
                        <ul id="admin-home-tabs" class="nav nav-tabs ng-scope" ng-if="areTabsVisible" role="tablist">
                    <!-- end ngIf: areTabsVisible -->
                    <div class="center-top ng-hide" skip-ng-show="yes" ng-activity-indicator="" ng-show="tabLevelLoading">
                    <div class="btc-group radiogroup">
                    <!--<radio-button-group data-toggle="buttons-radio" model="myModel" options="myOptions" id="idProperty" name="nameProperty" suffix="bootstrapSuffix"></radio-button-group>-->
                    <div class="" ng-show="myModel == 1" ng-class="{tabspaddedtop: myOptions.length == 0}">
                    <div class="ng-hide" ng-show="myModel == 2">
                    <div class="ng-hide" ng-show="myModel == 3">
                    <div class="ng-hide" ng-show="myModel == 4">
                    <div class="ng-hide" ng-show="myModel == 5">
                    <div class="ng-hide" ng-show="myModel == 6">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="show-message-dialog" class=" " style="display: none;;display: none;">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="center ng-hide" ng-show="AILoading" ng-activity-indicator="">
            <footer class="as-footer" ng-hide="AILoading" style="position: relative; bottom: 0px;">
     </div>
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="static/js/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"/>
<script src="static/js/bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"/>
<script src="static/js/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"/>
<script src="static/js/bower_components/typeahead.js/dist/typeahead.jquery.js"/>
<script src="static/js/bower_components/async/lib/async.js"/>
<script src="static/js/bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash.compat.js"/>
<script src="static/js/bower_components/moment/moment.js"/>
<script src="static/js/bower_components/angular/angular.js"/>
<script src="static/js/bower_components/ngActivityIndicator/ngActivityIndicator.js"/>
<script src="static/js/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"/>
<script src="static/js/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"/>
<script src="static/js/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"/>
<script src="static/js/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"/>
```

Below are the steps which I had tried:

1. Tried JavaScript but it also not working to locate any element in ubuntu server.
2. Verified: There is no version incompatibility of Window and ubuntu server configuration (like:-jre/jdk (1.8.0_65), FF 30, ANT 1.7.1 and with all jars including selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2 & selenium-java-2.48.2).
3. Selenium code not able to locate any element inside `<body>` tag.

**Require expertise guidance or solution will be highly appreciated! **

Comment: Did you try explicit wait until element gets visible.?

Comment: Yes, i have using the proper explicit wait, implicit wait and page load, its perfectly working  fine.

Comment: so your issue solved , right?

Comment: No, still having the same issue in ubuntu server (Note:- its working fine in window ff browser).

Comment: I have a similar problem with these "ng-hide" classes and alike in my project. And I am on Windows. I really tried different things which I've collected in many years of experience but webdriver so far is not handling Angular stuff gracefully.